# Ember.js with external handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, handlebars.js

So, I'm kind of new to `Ember.js` and it's been a couple of hours since I'm stuck with this. I'm playing with this [bloggr client](https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client) and what I want to accomplish is to load those `handlebars` templates from external files.

The "about" template should render when the user clicks the about page in the panel.
Here's the code in short so you dont have to dig that much (I believe it'll be easy for experienced users)

Template inside .`html` as shown in the example

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
<div class='about'>
  <p>Some text to be shown when users click ABOUT.</p>
</div>
```

Now what I've done is to take that `x-handlebar` code away from the `html` page and placed it (without the `<script type...>`) and then put it in `hbs/about.hbs`

Now, inside the html page I've done something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'hbs/about.hbs',         
    async: false,
    success: function (resp) {
      App.About = Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(resp),
      });
    }         
  });
```

The result of the ajax holds the content of the .hbs page, then I have to compile it so `Ember` can render it, right? Think that's what I did. But this is as far as I've come. Is what I've done right? What's the next move? I believe I have to append the content of the ajax call to the `body` or so.

Thanks in advance, after searching through SO I still wasn't able to make it run.

Comment: As an aside, I would recomment using Yeoman and generator-ember to scaffold out your project.  It is a great jumpstart to Ember so you can immediately get to the project rather than this sort of configuration exercise.  You want the final product to be done in as few requests and as quickly as possible.  Programmatically retrieving templates like this won't perform well.  You get linting and minification with Yeoman.  http://yeoman.io/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can attach a template to the object of available templates simply like so:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES.cow = Ember.Handlebars.compile("I'm a cow {{log this}}");
```

Or in your case maybe something like this:

```
var url = 'hbs/about.hbs',
    templateName = url.replace('.hbs', '');

Ember.$.ajax({
  url: url,         
  async: false,
  success: function (resp) {
    Em.TEMPLATES[templateName] = Ember.Handlebars.compile(resp);
  }         
});
```

Here's a lazy example of it being done in the application ready:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/apIRef/1/edit

To be honest precompiling the templates beforehand (server side) is more performant for the end user.

Precompiling takes the raw handlebars and turns it into a plethora of javascript statements for use when building your views.

When the DOM is ready Ember scans the DOM for script elements of type "text/x-handlebars" and calls compile on their contents.  It then adds the results to the `Ember.TEMPLATES` object with the name from the data-template-name attribute.  This can add some completely unnecessary load time to the application.

For example when we sent in "I'm a cow {{log this}}" it was converted into the following javascript method

```
function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data /**/) {
  this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
  helpers = this.merge(helpers, Ember.Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = '', hashTypes, hashContexts, escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;

  data.buffer.push("I'm a cow ");
  hashTypes = {};
  hashContexts = {};
  data.buffer.push(escapeExpression(helpers.log.call(depth0, "", {hash:{},contexts:[depth0],types:["ID"],hashContexts:hashContexts,hashTypes:hashTypes,data:data})));
  return buffer;
}
```

minimized to something ugly like this:

```
function anonymous(e,t,n,r,i){this.compilerInfo=[4,">= 1.0.0"];n=this.merge(n,Ember.Handlebars.helpers);i=i||{};var s="",o,u,a=this.escapeExpression;i.buffer.push("I'm a cow ");o={};u={};i.buffer.push(a(n.log.call(t,"",{hash:{},contexts:[t],types:["ID"],hashContexts:u,hashTypes:o,data:i})));return s}
```

Depending on what your back-end is you can compile and bundle your templates before hand and send them down in the html so you can avoid spending time compiling the templates client side.

Comment: So, let me know if I got this the right way. You precompiled the cow template and that's what you show once you click the link-to. Now, the goal is to load a template from another file, you're loading the code from .compile(code). This way I should go for some ajax in order to get to that file and retrieve the data right? I'm missing the point with your suggestion to precompile (isn't it always precompiled?). I'm trying to get the whole picture here, sorry.

Comment: No problem, ask as many questions as you want! See the updated answer.

Comment: amazing, not only worked but aldo cleared and few aspects from ember templates. Thanks again.